# Confirm program quit when cmd + Q is pressed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, windowlistener, system.exit

I have a program with a JFrame that I use a WindowListener to close the program with. I use the following method to prompt a message about saving changes made in the program:

```
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        if (condition) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

However, when I press cmd + Q, my program will quit without me having the option of saving. Is there a smart way to make sure that I can have a condition before I close my program regardless if I close it through the window X or through my keyboard short commands? Or do I need to create a KeyEvent for this?

Comment: `regardless if I close it through the window X or through my keyboard short commands? ` "cmd + Q" sounds like a Mac solution? In Windows you would use the keyboard accelerator assigned to the Exit menu item in the system menu to close the window. See [Closing an Application](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/01/closing-an-application/) for a basic solution that works in Windows whether you click on the "X" or use the keyboard accelerator. Don't know if it works differently in Mac.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the DefaultCloseOperation on JFrame and then dispose() the frame on windowClosing event (or System.exit(0) like you show above). Here is a simple working example:

```
JFrame f = new JFrame();
f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
f.pack();
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
   @Override
   public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we) {
      if (condition) {
         f.dispose();
      }
   }
});
f.setVisible(true);
```

This way all closing operation will use your condition.

Answer (score 0):

> However, when I press cmd + Q,

I believe that is a keystroke you enter from the command line?

If so you might be able to use `addShutDownHook(...)` method found in the `Runtime` class.